# Is it a good practice to have CMake-generated projects in repository?

Tags: version-control, cmake

If yes, which of generated files to commit? For example, for Visaul Studio 10, is it OK to commit only .vcxproj files and ignore the rest (i.e. *.cmake, CMakeFiles, etc)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is bad idea, because CMake performs checking of build tree before building, and if you move your build tree to another location (checkout your sources to another dir) you've got a configure error.

Comment: It's also bad because anyone else, whose system is slightly different, will have mysterious problems when trying to build. It sounds like @asd is trying to _build in-source_, which is a bad idea. I always build in a directory called `build`. If I want to guarantee a clean build or check a build with the default options, all I have to do is delete `build/`. This is **much** more difficult if the temporary build files are mixed in with the important (source) files!

Answer (score 2):

Usually one commits only the minimal set of files needed to build the project. Sometimes redundant files get into the repository for convenience.

I deduce from your question that you use `cmake` to generate `.vcxproj` files. In such situation people usually commit `CMakeLists` and such, since other files can be easily generated. Though I know some employers that would want you to do exactly vice versa...

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not a good practice. I upvoted Alexey's answer starting with "It is bad idea"...

CMake stores many full paths to entities that exist only on the machine where the configure step ran. All of its generated products should be considered valid only on that machine and never committed to a repository shared across multiple developers/machines.